# IQ Keyboard Manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

I am facing an issue with the IQ Keyboard codeless drop in, Whenever I try to click on text field the buttons move above the keyboard with a height similar to the keyboard's height but the buttons still work at the original position, The problem arises when I try on the real device on simulator it works fine. Please refer to the image[image]

Comment: Raise issue in github page

Comment: I'll surely do that  Prashant Tukadiya

Comment: Add some code corresponding with this question